# AngularJS: ng-repeat and scoped ng-click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-click

I have a series of list items populated by ng-repeat. Visibility is controlled by a simple ng-click and ng-show relationship. For the most part, this works just fine, but I want to be able to control the show/hide behavior with a global button that will show or hide *all* available items on the list.

Fair disclosure: I'm still very new to AngularJS. I'm aware that this is a scoping issue, but I'm not sure how to solve it. This is almost certainly a case of not knowing the right question to ask.

I have a jsfiddle here demonstrating my difficulty: http://jsfiddle.net/36BYs/838/

Sample HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">

  <span ng-show="!IsVisible" ng-click="isVisible = !isVisible;" >
    (show/hide all)
    <i class="fa fa-minus-square-o fa-small"></i>
  </span>
<ul>
        <li ng-repeat="mentor in mentors">
        <a ng-click="isVisible = !isVisible;">show/hide</a>
        <span ng-show="isVisible">{{mentor}}</span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Sample JS:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

function MainCtrl( $scope ) {
  $scope.isVisible = true;
  $scope.mentors = [ 'Jonathan', 'Nathan', 'Chris', 'Brian', 'Timothy' ];
}
```

It works fine as long as you have not independently toggled one of the list items. but If you click to show/hide on a particular line, the global ng-click loses control of the item.

Thanks in advance for any advice you can offer.

Comment: As you're aware, `ng-repeat` introduces a separate scope so that each `isVisible` underneath no longer tracks the parent `isVisible`. One solution is to explicitly track `isVisible` per item in addition to tracking a parent visibility state that overrides item-level one if necessary. Demo—https://jsfiddle.net/uLykhg0z/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While other comments have been useful, user miqid's comment provided the best answer to my specific need:

> As you're aware, ng-repeat introduces a separate scope so that each isVisible underneath no longer tracks the parent isVisible. One solution is to explicitly track isVisible per item in addition to tracking a parent visibility state that overrides item-level one if necessary. Demo—jsfiddle.net/uLykhg0z – miqid 14 hours ago

The jsfiddle is a variation on Andrew Shepherd's solution (jsfiddle.net/uLykhg0z):

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">

  <span ng-show="!IsVisible" class = "clickable" ng-click="toggleVisibility()" >
    (show/hide all)
    <i class="fa fa-minus-square-o fa-small"></i>
  </span>
  <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="mentor in mentors">
        <a class = "clickable" ng-click="mentor.isVisible = !mentor.isVisible;">show/hide</a>
        <span ng-show="mentor.isVisible">{{mentor.name}}</span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

function MainCtrl( $scope ) {
    var isVisible = true;
  $scope.mentors = [
    { name: 'Jonathan', isVisible: true },
    { name: 'Nathan', isVisible: true },
    { name: 'Chris', isVisible: true },
    { name: 'Brian', isVisible: true },
    { name: 'Timothy', isVisible: true },
  ];
  $scope.toggleVisibility = function () {
    isVisible = !isVisible;
    $scope.mentors = $scope.mentors.map(function (mentor) {
        mentor.isVisible = isVisible;
      return mentor;
    });
  };
}
```

This allowed me to accommodate some more complex nesting that I have to deal with in a tree structure.

Thanks again for all of your help, folks!

Answer (score 1):

It appears that, on the initial render, angular is attempting to evaluate `isVisible` for each mentor. Because `mentor.isVisible` will be `undefined`, the angular framework uses the parent scope's `isVisible`.

But then, when you toggle one particular mentor, you effectively assign an `isVisible` boolean property to that particular `mentor` string. (Because you can happily attach additional properties to a `string` in javascript).

After this, you can toggle `show/hide all`, and it will affect each mentor that has not had their own `isVisible` property assigned to.

It demonstrates how confusing scoping was in the initial version of AngularJS.

Here is a working answer: http://jsfiddle.net/fkw5923t/

I have made some changes:

- Rather than assign values to `$scope`, I'm using the `controllerName as mnemonic` syntax. In the controller code I assign values to `this` rather then `$scope`. I prefer this approach, because now the scoping is clear and explicit
- I've changed `mentor` from a string to an object, consisting of two values: `name` and `isVisible`. Again, this now makes the scoping rules clear and explicit.

The HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl as mainCtrl">

  <span class = "clickable" ng-click="mainCtrl.isVisible = !mainCtrl.isVisible;" >
    (show/hide all)
    <i class="fa fa-minus-square-o fa-small"></i>
  </span>
<ul ng-show="mainCtrl.isVisible">
        <li ng-repeat="mentor in mainCtrl.mentors">
        <a class = "clickable" ng-click="mentor.isVisible = !mentor.isVisible;">show/hide</a>
        <span ng-show="mentor.isVisible">{{ mentor.name }}</span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The javascript:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

function MainCtrl() {
  this.isVisible = true;
  var mentorNames = ['Jonathan', 'Nathan', 'Chris', 'Brian', 'Timothy'];
  this.mentors = mentorNames.map(
      name => { 
         return { 
             name:name, 
             isVisible:true 
         }; 
      }
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller("myCtrl", function ($scope) {
  $scope.mentors = [
    'Jonathan',
    'Nathan',
    'Chris',
    'Brian',
    'Timothy'
  ];
  
  $scope.showAll = function() {
    $scope.visibleMentors = $scope.mentors.slice();
  };
  
  $scope.hideAll = function() {
    $scope.visibleMentors = [];
  };
  
  $scope.isVisible = function(mentor) {
    return $scope.visibleMentors.includes(mentor);
  };
  
  $scope.show = function(mentor) {
    $scope.visibleMentors.push(mentor);
  };
  
  $scope.hide = function(mentor) {
    $scope.visibleMentors.splice($scope.visibleMentors.indexOf(mentor), 1);
  };
  
  $scope.showAll();
});
```

```css
a {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <button ng-click="showAll()">show all</button>
    <button ng-click="hideAll()">hide all</button>                                                                                                                                                                           
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="mentor in mentors">
        <a ng-show="isVisible(mentor)" ng-click="hide(mentor)">hide</a>
        <a ng-show="!isVisible(mentor)" ng-click="show(mentor)">show</a>
        <span ng-show="isVisible(mentor)">
          {{mentor}}
        </span>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```